# Display MsgBox within Powerpoint from Excel Macro

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I have an Excel macro that creates a PowerPoint from the Excel data. What I am wanting to do is display a success message in PowerPoint once the code has finished.

Here is part of my code:

```
'Step 1: Declare your variables
  Dim PP As PowerPoint.Application
  Dim PPPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
  Dim PPSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
  Dim SlideTitle As String
```

And here is what I have tried that gives an error.

```
PP.MsgBox "The macro has finished"
```

For added clarity, I am not asking how to display the msg within Excel (where the macro is run). I am wanting the msgbox on the PPT because that is the active window once the macro starts its processes.

Comment: Perhaps helpful: https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/index.php?thread/96115-show-msgbox-from-excel-in-powerpoint/

Comment: What makes you think `MsgBox` is a method of the application object of powerpoint. `VBA.MsgBox`  would make sense but `PP.MsgBox` will not work. Please have a look at the documentation [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.application) [2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/msgbox-function). What you could try is `AppActivate PP.Name` before `MsgBox "The macro has finished"`